# opción click pantalla Android studio

Tags: android-studio

tengo la siguiente parte de programa:

```
   holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
            if(!isLongClick){
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getLink()));
                mContext.startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Supuestamente al hacer click debería de abrirme el enlace, pero no me funciona y no se el motivo..

adjunto objectRSS

```
   public class RssObject
{
    public String status ;
    public Feed feed;
    public List<Item> items;


public RssObject(String status, Feed feed, List<Item> items) {
    this.status = status;
    this.feed = feed;
    this.items = items;

}

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Feed getFeed() {
        return feed;
    }

    public void setFeed(Feed feed) {
        this.feed = feed;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

no consigo ver cual es motivo y no tengo ningún tipo de error simplemente no abre nada.. :S

gracias!

Comment: rssObject.getItems().get(position).getLink() tiene un url? ya revisaste esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeramente debes asegurar que el objeto en verdad tiene una url definida :

```
rssObject.getItems().get(position).getLink()
```

además no es necesario determinar "isLongClick", esto si deseas que con un simple click se abra la url en el browser:

```
 holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
            //if(!isLongClick){
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getLink()));
                mContext.startActivity(browserIntent);
            //}
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ostras cuando te refieres a url definida que quieres decir? que quieres que mire o que incorpore?

Comment: no me mates.. voy aprendiendo poco a poco xD :P

Comment: Recuerdas lo que comenté acerca de "debugging"? al menos imprime la url en el LogCat para saber que contenido tiene Log.i("Valor montse", "Url :" +rssObject.getItems().get(position).getLink());

Comment: estoy buscando de hacerlo pero no se como hacerlo. se donde esta logCat.. etc

Comment: Ostras Montse!, revisa este tutorial, es importante el uso del LogCat: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Comment: la duda que tengo es que quieres que busque ? esto?  Log.i(mContext, "Url :" +rssObject.getItems().get(position).getLink());

Comment: me da este error 10-24 17:39:29.600 2614-2614/eac2.eac2_maqueda_m E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67605/discussion-on-answer-by-jorgesys-opcion-click-pantalla-android-studio).

Comment: @MontseMkd ¿en verdad la otra respuesta es correcta? =-\